# Use metric's value as a value of another metric's label

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible to use the value of some metric as the value of label of another metric?

Let's say I have two metrics: `metric_a` and `metric_b`. `metric_a` also has `some_label` label. I'd like to make a query like the following:

`metric_a{some_label=metric_b}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use metrics like that, however if you want to specify `metric_a` that shares a label value with `metric_b` you can do:

```
metric_a and on (some_label) metric_b
```

Answer (score 4):

You can, although it's quite the hack:

```
metric_a and count_values without() ("some_label", metric_b)
```

The `count_values` function is going to essentially add a `some_label` label to your `metric_b`, equal to `metric_b`'s value. The actual value is going to be 1, but you're not interested in that, just in constructing the right labelset to filter your `metric_a` by.

Also, you may need to pay attention to how you represent your value. E.g. there are more ways of representing the value 1 (`"1"`, `"1.0"`, `"1e0"` etc.) and `count_values` will only produce `"1"` as output.